# capacity of a close bounded interval in the plane

Tags: measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory

I am new to the topic of capacities and I am working in questions, like what is the capacity of a line segment?. In [Some properties of capacity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728179/some-properties-of-capacity)  there is a really nice answer to the question posted there, my question is under the same argument given in this answer can I claim that $\text{cap}_{p}([a,b])=0$?. Here I am thinking that $[a,b]$  is a bounded closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What's an interval in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Is it actually 1D, i.e. $\{ x \} \times [a,b]$ or similar?

Comment: I edited the question but yes, it is pretty much that.

Comment: I think what you really want to ask about is the set $\{\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)x_2: \lambda\in [0,1]\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ for given $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes, You are right. Thank you.

Comment: @TwainNick it is positive. this and more is done in the book by Ransford, potential theory in the complex plane.